# autocommand variable is not substituded

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, substitute, variables

```
let Dropbox = "/usr/Dropbox"
...

  autocmd BufNewFile  *.php 0r Dropbox/vim/templates/php_start.txt
```

*The variable 'Dropbox' is not substituded by its value*

Comment: You need to evaluate the variable first, using `:exe`. I am sure there are already several answers here that explain this

Comment: Please try to format future questions as actual questions, rather than a statement of something that occurred. It is otherwise difficult to figure out what is being asked.